# How to redirect php while the shell_exec() command is running at background?

Tags: php, redirect, cmd, execute

When the button is clicked a PHP page is called which in turn executes the shell_exec() command which fires a python script. The problem is that the python script will take almost 30 minutes to executes and the browser stays in process until the script actually finishes. So, is there a way so that when the shell_exec command is fired it returns back whereas the python script starts in the background?

```
if(isset($_POST['fire_automation_now'])){

    $cmd = "python schedule_php.py now";
    shell_exec($cmd); 
    header('location:index.php');   

}
```

Now its doesn't redirect to index.php until the python script which is scheduled to run 30 minutes ends.

Currently I am just creating a text file after 300s delay just to imitate the wait in script.

HTML

```
<form action="fire_automation.php" method="POST">
  <div class=" row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <button type="submit" name="fire_automation_now" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Run Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fire_automation_now'])){

    $cmd = "python schedule_php.py now";
    shell_exec($cmd); 
    header('location:index.php');   

}?>
```

PYTHON

```
import time

def now():
    time.sleep(300)
    open("test.txt", "w")

def main(choice):
    if choice == "now":
        now()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Thanks.

Comment: And how is this a Python question exactly ??? (=> tag removed, please think twice before adding unrelated tags next time).

Comment: Maybe you didn't paste the whole Python script but if you did, you are missing the import of the "sys" module.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-shot running of your Python script you may just run it in the background like so:

```
shell_exec("python schedule_php.py now > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

Or combine that call with `nohup` if it doesn't work that way.

Comment: The browser now gets redirect without the calling the script and since its on windows therefore cannot use nohup.

Comment: Well, there's a multitude of stuff that can go wrong. For instance, does the PHP script find the Python interpreter? Does the Python interpreter find the script?

Comment: well it ran before with including the new script. Should I post my whole code?

Comment: I tried my PHP call with you Python script and it worked – on Linux, though.

Comment: The '&' for running processes doesn't work in Windows. You might try to use the Powershell cmdlet 'Start-Process -NoNewWindow ... '.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

in PHP. then command will run in the background

Comment: The browser now gets redirect without the calling the script

Comment: Posted. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php):

> When running PHP as a command line script, and the script's tty goes away without the script being terminated then the script will die the next time it tries to write anything, unless value is set to TRUE

Note:

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see flush().